# Keep selected dropdown result after refreshing page, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

**Situation:**

I have a page with multiple tables using the [datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/index) plugin, I so made that it only shows 1 at the time and you can select through a dropdown menu which one you want to display on your screen.

**Problem:**

When I go to another page on my website and comeback it goes back to table1 from the dropdown menu or when you refresh the whole page it goes back to table1 even when you selected another table to display. Now I wrote a piece of jquery to keep them selected but here comes the problem. When I select one it only shows me in the dropdown menu the right choice but it keep displaying table1 because that is the first option in the dropdown menu. I hope its a bit clear what I try to explain.

**My question:**

How can I display the right table from the dropdown options? Even when you refreshed the page

**My code so far:**

I already tried a couple of things and I will post them down below. Maybe you guys can see what's the issue. It doesn't give any errors.

*Html code:*

```
<div class='dropdown'>
        <select onchange="showMov(this.value);" id='drop' name="mov_type" class='form-control'>
        <option class='keuze' value='table1' selected>Computer</option>
        <option class='keuze' value='table2'>Monitor</option>
        <option class='keuze' value='table3'>Software</option>
        <option class='keuze' value='table4'>Gebruiker</option>
        <option class='keuze' value='table5'>Randapparatuur</option>
        <option class='keuze' value='table6'>Telefoon</option>
        <option class='keuze' value='table7'>Tablet</option>
        <option class='keuze' value='table8'>Laptop</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

*My js code for the refreshing:*

```
function showMov(val) {
  sessionStorage.setItem('SelectedItem', val);

  switch (val) {
    case 'table2':
      {
        $('#table1_form').hide();
        $('#table3_form').hide();
        $('#table4_form').hide();
        $('#table5_form').hide();
        $('#table6_form').hide();
        $('#table7_form').hide();
        $('#table8_form').hide();
        $('#table2_form').show();
        break;
      }
      case 'table3':
      {
        $('#table1_form').hide();
        $('#table2_form').hide();
        $('#table4_form').hide();
        $('#table5_form').hide();
        $('#table6_form').hide();
        $('#table7_form').hide();
        $('#table8_form').hide();
        $('#table3_form').show();
        break;
      }
      case 'table4':
      {
        $('#table1_form').hide();
        $('#table2_form').hide();
        $('#table3_form').hide();
        $('#table5_form').hide();
        $('#table6_form').hide();
        $('#table7_form').hide();
        $('#table8_form').hide();
        $('#table4_form').show();
        break;
      }
      case 'table5':
      {
        $('#table1_form').hide();
        $('#table2_form').hide();
        $('#table3_form').hide();
        $('#table4_form').hide();
        $('#table6_form').hide();
        $('#table7_form').hide();
        $('#table8_form').hide();
        $('#table5_form').show();
        break;
      }
      case 'table6':
      {
        $('#table1_form').hide();
        $('#table2_form').hide();
        $('#table3_form').hide();
        $('#table4_form').hide();
        $('#table5_form').hide();
        $('#table7_form').hide();
        $('#table8_form').hide();
        $('#table6_form').show();
        break;
      }
      case 'table7':
      {
        $('#table1_form').hide();
        $('#table2_form').hide();
        $('#table3_form').hide();
        $('#table4_form').hide();
        $('#table5_form').hide();
        $('#table6_form').hide();
        $('#table8_form').hide();
        $('#table7_form').show();
        break;
      }
      case 'table8':
      {
        $('#table1_form').hide();
        $('#table2_form').hide();
        $('#table3_form').hide();
        $('#table4_form').hide();
        $('#table5_form').hide();
        $('#table6_form').hide();
        $('#table7_form').hide();
        $('#table8_form').show();
        break;
      }
    default:
      {
        $('#table2_form').hide();
        $('#table3_form').hide();
        $('#table4_form').hide();
        $('#table5_form').hide();
        $('#table6_form').hide();
        $('#table7_form').hide();
        $('#table8_form').hide();
      }
  }
}

$(function() {
  var selMovType = document.getElementById('drop');
  var selectedItem = sessionStorage.getItem('SelectedItem');

    if (selectedItem) {
    selMovType.value = selectedItem;
  }
});
```

*My js code for switching tables in the dropdown menu:*

```
$(function () {

    $('#table1').wrap('<div id="hidetable1"  class="hide" style="display:none"/>');
    $('#table2').wrap('<div id="hidetable2"  class="hide" style="display:none"/>');
    $('#table3').wrap('<div id="hidetable3"  class="hide" style="display:none"/>');
    $('#table4').wrap('<div id="hidetable4"  class="hide" style="display:none"/>');
    $('#table5').wrap('<div id="hidetable5"  class="hide" style="display:none"/>');
    $('#table6').wrap('<div id="hidetable6"  class="hide" style="display:none"/>');
    $('#table7').wrap('<div id="hidetable7"  class="hide" style="display:none"/>');
    $('#table8').wrap('<div id="hidetable8"  class="hide" style="display:none"/>');


    $('#table1').DataTable( {
      "searching": true,
      "lengthMenu": [[18, -1], [18, "All"]],
      "columnDefs": [{  "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [-1] }, { "bSearchable":false, "aTargets": [-1] }],
      "stateSave": true
    } );
    $('#table2').DataTable( {
      "searching": true,
      "lengthMenu": [[18, -1], [18, "All"]],
      "columnDefs": [{  "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [-1] }, { "bSearchable":false, "aTargets": [-1] }],
      "stateSave": true
    } );
    $('#table3').DataTable( {
      "searching": true,
      "lengthMenu": [[18, -1], [18, "All"]],
      "columnDefs": [{  "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [-1] }, { "bSearchable":false, "aTargets": [-1] }],
      "stateSave": true
    } );
    $('#table4').DataTable( {
      "searching": true,
      "lengthMenu": [[18, -1], [18, "All"]],
      "columnDefs": [{  "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [-1] }, { "bSearchable":false, "aTargets": [-1] }],
      "stateSave": true
    } );
    $('#table5').DataTable( {
      "searching": true,
      "lengthMenu": [[18, -1], [18, "All"]],
      "columnDefs": [{  "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [-1] }, { "bSearchable":false, "aTargets": [-1] }],
      "stateSave": true
    } );
    $('#table6').DataTable( {
      "searching": true,
      "lengthMenu": [[18, -1], [18, "All"]],
      "columnDefs": [{  "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [-1] }, { "bSearchable":false, "aTargets": [-1] }],
      "stateSave": true
    } );
    $('#table7').DataTable( {
      "searching": true,
      "lengthMenu": [[18, -1], [18, "All"]],
      "columnDefs": [{  "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [-1] }, { "bSearchable":false, "aTargets": [-1] }],
      "stateSave": true
    } );
    $('#table8').DataTable( {
      "searching": true,
      "lengthMenu": [[18, -1], [18, "All"]],
      "columnDefs": [{  "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [-1] }, { "bSearchable":false, "aTargets": [-1] }],
      "stateSave": true
    } );
    console.log($("#drop"))
    $("#hide"+ $("#drop")[0].value).show(); 
       $("#drop").change(function () {
            var end = this.value;
            $('.hide').hide();
           $("#hide"+end).show(); 
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: You can either store the values in localstorage, cach or cookies, another easier way but maybe not what you need is to store the info in a hidden input. Inputs stores the value its given for a short while

Comment: You need to `trigger` change event on selectbox after setting value to it. Like - `selMovType.value = selectedItem; $(selMovType).trigger('change');`

Comment: @Patte I'm using sessionstorage over localstorage just because I don't want the website to remember your values after coming back to the website

Comment: @J.Ende I might remember wrong but i think you can set a timeout on local storage, and you can also delete it when a user leaves the page

Comment: @Patte How would you write it than with local storage? and btw I think the problem mostly lays in the other JS file down at the console.log part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a dumb way of doing it but sometimes dumb ideas work :)

```
// Store the div(or other element) html in the storage
localStorage.setItem("data", "Your_html");

// Retrieve your stored html
document.getElementById("show_in_this_div").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("data");
```

Comment: You got me on the way, I think the problem wasn't which way of storage. Since it kept remembering the dropdown menu value but not the value in my menuswitch.js file so it always showed me the first selected table. When I find a solution I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

On your js code responsible for switching between table view, you should call `sessionStorage.getItem` to retrieve the last selected view.
Then simply call `show()` on the correct element.

Answer (score 0):

Save selected valuet into `cookie` or in `localStorage`. When on load, check if there is some valuer saved, if exists, set this value to select.